# Check if there are records during migration

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework-migrations

I want to create a migration that creates an admin user with specific role. I wanted to include an assert to check that that role actually exists and that there are no existing users with that role, but apparently there are no methods in `System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigration` for inserting records, selecting records or getting any kind of feedback. Even `DbMigration.Sql` returns void.

So far I see the only way to make this migration is to write it all in one big **.sql** file.

Comment: Is this using ASP.NET Identity? In that case you will need a UserManager and RoleManager.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it at `Seed` method inside `Configuration` class instead, do not create blank migration for that.

**Example (correct it on your own!)**:

```
//checking is role exists
var roleExist = context.Roles.Any(x => x.Name == "MyRole");

//no existing users with that role
var withRoles = context.User2Roles.Any(x => x.Role.Name == "MyRole");

//Add or update admin user
context.Users.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Email, new User { EMail = "Admin" });

//get admin and role after creating them, if it needed(code not presented)
var role = context.Roles.Where(x => x.Name == "MyRole").First();
var admin = context.Users.Where(x => x.Email == "Admin").First();

//add role to admin if role not already was linked to him, checking code not presented
context.User2Roles.Add(new User2Roles{ User = admin, Role = role });
context.SaveChanges();
```